# Как исправить юникод вместо русского языка symfony?

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

Когда я достаю объект из бд, вместо русского языка достается такое:

```
\u041a\u0440\u0435\u0434\u0438\u044
```

Пробовал и в миграциях при создании таблицы использовать

```
DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE `utf8mb4_unicode_ci`
```

Тем не менее, не помогает

В чем может быть проблема? и как её решить?

Добавлю ещё, что при отработке запроса, русский язык показывается в Pretty адекватно (юзаю постам), но в Raw юникод, что мешает работе фронту

Comment: \JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE